# Variable indel costs for sequences of unequal length

Tags: traminer

I am doing Sequence Analysis in TraMineR using the Optimal Matching algorithm. Unfortunately, my **sequences are of unequal length due to right-censored data**. The minimum length of my sequences is 5, the maximum length 11. The variations in length are not meaningful for the dissimilarities between sequences that I am interested in. Therefore, I want to hold the influence of unequal length on the overall dissimilarities between sequences as small as possible.

I read a possible solution to this problem in Stovel and Bolan (2004 (1)), who use **variable indel costs** depending on whether or not the sequences are of equal length. So, for sequences of equal length they use fixed indel costs, and for unequal length they use a reduced cost, which is "roughly one-fourth of the fixed cost”.

**My questions would be:** 
In general, how should the missings be coded in TraMineR? As void elements or should I include a missing state into the alphabet? 
Is there an option in TraMineR to apply variable indel costs, as introduced by Stovel and Bolan? If yes, how can this be done?

---

(1) Stovel, Katherine and Marc Bolan. 2004. "Residential Trajectories: Using Optimal Alignment to Reveal the Structure of Residential Mobility." Sociological Methods & Research 32(4):559-598.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to use variable indel costs(depending on whether or not the sequences are of equal length). I am quite sceptic regarding this method, because, if I understand it well, the definition of the distance measure change according to the sequences involved (since the indel costs change). For this reason, the triangle inequality is not respected. From a conceptual point of view, I think that we should always use the same comparison criteria, and thus the same distance definition.

Comment: What does it mean that the triangle inequality is not respected? Why is this a problem?